# What does a conversion imply in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

For few days I've been wondering why an std_logic_vector type can't get an unsigned/signed type.

My question is : does this constraint only comes from VHDL syntax and though this is implicitly needed by the compiler or does it have a real impact after synthesis and if so, how?

In other terms I'd like to know what are the effects of this :

```
signal my_slv_signal : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal my_unsigned_signal : unsigned(7 downto 0);

my_slv_signal <= std_logic_vector(my_unsigned_signal);
```

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438516/vhdl-std-logic-vector-conversion-to-signed-and-unsigned-with-numeric-std)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not looking for information about the to_unsigned/to_signed or to_stdlogicvector functions of the numeric_std library. I know those functions return "std_logic_vector(input)" (or unsigned(...) / signed(...)). I'd like to know what those last conversions (without the "to_") are actually doing.

Comment: Or here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403835/how-expensive-is-data-type-conversion-vs-bit-array-manipulation-in-vhdl/27404061#27404061